# Flutter: How to align inner Button to left side of outer Button

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to place the inner grey Button inside the red Button, but cant find a way to align it to the left side of the red button.

Excuse my bad code, im new to flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MainApp(),
));

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 100, 50, 0),
        child: SizedBox(
          child: ButtonTheme(
            height: 70,
            child: FlatButton(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ButtonTheme(
                      height: 70,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: Text(""),
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what im getting, and im trying to get rid of the red space on the left side of the innner Button.

[image]

Comment: Minor tangent, why are you trying to put a button inside a button?

Comment: @Abion47, i just realized that i can fill a button with a container without having to make the container clickable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have pointed out, we are not sure of your motivation for having a button inside of a button.... however, if you actually need this for some reason, here is the solution:

```
SizedBox(
  child: ButtonTheme(
    height: 70,
    child: FlatButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // ADD THIS LINE
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            ButtonTheme(
              height: 70,
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text(""),
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Basically, `FlatButton()` has a padding parameter, which is used to control this spacing that you are referring to, as well as the 0-width space above and below the grey button and the equivalent space on the right side of the button. Passing in `EdgeInsets.zero` makes sure there is no padding on any interior side of the button.

Hope this helps

Comment: @user8385652 hope this helps you solve it, if you in fact need a button inside a button.

Comment: I actually noticed that i don't but thank you very much for the solution!